# disable elements when value = 1, enable them when value > 1

Tags: javascript, html, input, disable

Using javascript only I am trying to say `if cycn = 1`, disable input element with `id="prevdl"`

`if cycn > 1`, then do not disable element with `id="prevdl"`, and in both cases
preview the value of cycn in the `<p>` with `id="transit"`

but condition after `if (cycn = 1)` is executed no matter what. And the one after else is not seen at all

HTML

```
<label for="cyclecount">Cycle Count:</label>
<input type="number" id="cyccnt" name="cyclecount" placeholder="Today's cycle number" min="1" max="6" autocomplete="off" value=""><br><br>

<p id="transit"></p>

<label for="previousdoseLevel">Previous Dose Level:</label>
<input type="number" id="prevdl" name="previousdoseLevel" placeholder="Insert Previous Dose Level" autocomplete="off" value=""><br><br>
```

Javascript

```
var cyc = document.getElementById("cyccnt");
var cycn = Number(cyc.value);
document.getElementById("cyccnt").oninput = function (e) { 
    if (cycn = 1) {
        document.getElementById("prevdl").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("transit").innerHTML = cycn;   
    } else if (cycn >1) {
        document.getElementById("prevdl").disabled = false; 
        document.getElementById("transit").innerHTML = cycn;    
    }
    e.preventDefault(e);
}
```

please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: You are using only one equal sign in the line `if (cycn = 1)`, which is the _assignment_ operator; you should use two equal signs instead (`if (cycn == 1)`) for the _equality_ operator

Comment: `var cycn = Number(cyc.value);`  get the value on start, and never de updated

Answer (score 0):

use double `==`

```
if (cycn == 1) {
  document.getElementById("prevdl").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("transit").innerHTML = cycn;   
}
```

and take the value from the event instead.

```
document.getElementById("cyccnt").oninput = function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var value = e.target.value
  document.getElementById("transit").innerHTML = value;    
  if (value && +value == 1) {
    document.getElementById("prevdl").disabled = true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("prevdl").disabled = false; 
  }
}
```

Comment: i tried it but still did'nt work

Comment: it finally worked but i entered the variables within the function, thanks a million